# Use callto protocol with Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, url-scheme

I want to use `callto` to initiate video calls on Teams.

Something like:

```html
<a href="callto:test@example.com">start call</a>
```

This worked at first, but after about 3 calls it switched to always popping up a "Calling disabled by your administrator" message.

I *am* the administrator, and there appears to be nothing in the Team admin portal to govern this.

A support call to Microsoft ended with them insisting this was a bug on my end and not an issue with Teams.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello @Keith - We have test it in Classic Teams and it is working fine but we are facing this issue in New Teams client, so we have informed engineering team. Are you also facing this issue only in New Teams client?

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft we definitely have it in the new Teams PWA/Electron-ish app, and that's what all our users are on. I'm not sure whether it would work if I install Classic. Do you have a bug reference or similar for the known issue?